# pipe command make standard input broken

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pipe

I have two processes: `t1.cpp` and `t2.cpp`.

`t1.cpp` and `t2.cpp` are simplified ,I want to describe the problem easily.

```
//t1.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "hello\n"
         << "world\n"
         << "ok ok\n";
    return 0;
}

//t2.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{
    string str;
    while(getline(cin,str)){
        cout << str <<endl;
    }

    //cin.clear();
    //flush the cin
    //cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    char x;
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling `t1.cpp` and `t2.cpp`. I execute them in this way `./t1 | ./t2`.

Problems occur! `cin >> x;` in `t2.cpp` failed! I have no chance to type from the keyboard.

It seems the pipe command implements by `redirecting the STDIN_FILENO`. Does it forbid the standard input simultaneously?

My harsh requirements is obtain data from the output of `t1` with shell command `|`,in addition,I want interact with users in `t2`.For example,I would  display `Sure to del?[y/n],and wait users's anwser.`

Comment: Not really a C++ question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103885/piping-data-to-a-processs-stdin-without-causing-eof-afterward

Comment: I think the right answer is “do <thing that `less` does>”, but I don’t know what that is. Does it read from `/dev/tty`? Then how come I can reliably send input to whatever command I’m piping to `less`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,we deal this problem using "/dev/tty"

```
FILE *file = fopen("/dev/tty","r");
if(NULL == file){
    /*error*/
}
int ch = fgetc(file);
if('y' == ch || 'Y' == ch){
    /*balabala*/
}
```

when `stdin` or `stdout` was redirected , we also can read or write from the `/dev/tty`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is something you can do in the C++ code. `t1` has to read from stdin and echo that to stdout, which is redirected. You can do something like this at various places:

```
T value;
std::cin >> value;
std::cout << value;
```

Or to emulate the behaviour of the shell command in the comments (append stdin after `t1` has finished writing its data to stdout):

```
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
          std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

Comment: This can work, but isn’t really the best solution because it mixes the two input sources; you can’t tell what came from `t1` and what came from the user. Plus if you pipe into `t1` you lose the user input again.